# Add months to a date using formula field

Tags: apex, formula-field, configuration

I have a requirement. On opportunity there is a field Min Term (months) and a closedate field(standard). 
Need to create a check box field "Opp 50% expired". It will be auto-ticked when closedate + minTerm/2 > today.

I tried to achieve by creating the formula field but found that we can't add months to a date.
Tried to use some custom formula but they also do not work in all scenarios.

Can we do this using apex ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you look at https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&language=en_US ?  scroll down to see sfdc help's answer on adding months to dates for a non apex solution. read the limitations carefully

Answer (score 1):

While I think this could be done with code relatively easy, I think you can do this without code as well. Here is something you might want to explore:

1. Create a new formula field called "50% date field. (mt__c is the name of the min term field)

   ```
   DATE(
   IF( MONTH( CloseDate ) + (VALUE(TEXT(mt__c)) / 2) >12, YEAR(CloseDate) + 1,YEAR(CloseDate)),
   IF( MONTH( CloseDate ) + (VALUE(TEXT(mt__c)) / 2) >12, FLOOR(MOD(MONTH( CloseDate ) + (VALUE(TEXT(mt__c)) / 2),12)), MONTH( CloseDate ) + (VALUE(TEXT(mt__c)) / 2)),
   DAY(CloseDate) + MOD(30*(VALUE(TEXT(mt__c))/2),30))
   ```
2. Create a new Workflow rule on Opportunity object to automatically check the checkbox 0 hours after that formula date.
   [image]
3. Create a field update to check the checkbox "Opp 50% expired"; This should happen 0 hours after the formularized 50% date field.
4. You'll probably need to extend this, or create another workflow rule, to handle the case of when the we're already passed the midpoint of the min term + the close date. That should be considerably easier than this workflow rule.

Best of luck!

-Wes

Comment: @user2328 Were you able to get your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Apex offers an addMonths method:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_addMonths

That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new(ish) addMonths formula function:

[image]

..so no apex or test classes are necessary